# Maximum length of a XEX-encrypted scheme?

Tags: tweakable-cipher

Suppose that:

- $\widetilde{E}: \mathcal{K} \times \mathcal{T} \times \mathcal{PT} \rightarrow \mathcal{CT}$ and $\widetilde{D}: \mathcal{K} \times \mathcal{T} \times \mathcal{CT} \rightarrow \mathcal{PT}$.
- $\widetilde{E}(K, T, X) = E(K, T) \oplus E(K, X \oplus E(K, T))$ and $\widetilde{D}(K, T, X) = E(K, T) \oplus D(K, X \oplus E(K, T))$ where $K = \{0, 1\}^{k}$, $T = \{0, 1\}^{t}$, and $X = \{0, 1\}^{n}$
- $CT_{i} = \widetilde{E}(K, IV \boxplus i, PT_{i})$ and $PT_{i} = \widetilde{D}(K, IV \boxplus i, CT_{i})$.

What is the maximum length data stream that I can encrypt with a given pair of $K$ and $IV$ using this tweakable block cipher scheme and why?